# best approach in javascript/jquery lo populate oblects from xml data

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm a beginner in js. I'm pulling a xml from a server (no json available), and I want to display it on a web page. I got the request working, also I managed to access the data in the xml tree. Both using jquery. They are data from the congress, congressman's data. I'd like to make a bunch of Congressman objects and populate them with data from xml. They go like:

in xml:

```
<congressman>
  <name> jhon </name>
  .
  . a lot of data
  .<id>1234</id>
</congressman>
```

can i make an object like:

```
function Congressman(XML.node){
     name: this.name,
     .
     .
     .
     id: this.id
}
```

and pass the node as an argument constructing new Congressmans?
or i need to loop trough each data individually in every congressman returned?
like:

```
 var name =  $(root).find("congressman").find("name").text();
    var id   =  $(root).find("congressman").find("id").text();

 and assign it to a Congressman obj?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `each` [1] in jQuery to iterate the selected elements.

for example

```
var congressmanArray = []; // for stored congressman data

$(root).find('congressman').each(function(){

   // collected data
   var cman = {};
   cman.id = $(this).find('id').text();    
   cman.name = $(this).find('name').text();  
   // ....
   congressmanArray.push(cman);

});
```

In the end you will get congressman data as JSON.

so if your data have only one level child just...

```
var congressmanArray = []; // for stored congressman data

$(root).find('congressman').each(function(){

   // collected data
   var cman = {};
   $(this).find('>*').each(function(){
       var tagName = $(this).prop('tagName');
       cman[tagName] = $(this).text();
   });
   congressmanArray.push(cman);

});
```

Hope this help!

[1] http://api.jquery.com/each/